# Change 'New Quick Note' keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, notes.app

How to change the shortcut fn+Q to create a quick note to another hotkey?
My Logitech K380 doesn't support fn+letters as valid hotkeys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Mission Control (left pane) > Quick Note (last item in right pane).